# AWS EC2 Problema com o Disco

Tags: centos, amazon-aws

Uso a Amazon e tenho uma instancia EC2 rodando CentOS 6.5.

Eu recentemente fui trocar o disco da maquina. fiz o procedimento de desligar a maquina fazer um snapshot do disco antigo e subir em um novo com o espaço maior.

Quando religuei a maquina ele me mostra que a partição barra tem 7.8GB. QUando na verdade o disco novo é de 20GB.

Comando df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde       7,8G  7,3G   90M  99% /
tmpfs           828M     0  828M   0% /dev/shm
```

Comando lsblk:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvde 202:64   0  20G  0 disk /
xvdj 202:144  0   8G  0 disk
```

Se reparar a partiçao /dev/xvde tem 20GB e está montada corretamente so que na informação da partição so aparece 8GB.

Att.

Comment: Quando vc executa `df -a` exibe as informações corretamente?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Exibe a informação errada dizendo que o disco tem 8GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de aumentar o volume, você precisa redimensionar o sistema de arquivos com `resize2fs` ou similar. Como descrito [nesta parte da documentação](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, faltou apenas eu executar o comando de resize.